# Why is db2_fetch_assoc not consistently finding results? MySQL->DB2 conversion

Tags: php, db2

I am converting a PHP app from MySQL to DB2 and there seems to be something different between the IBM_DB2 and MySQL PHP extensions that I can't understand or resolve.

`db2_fetch_array()` does not seem to be able to return a row from the recordset if I call it outside the function that contained `db2_connect()` and `db2_exec()`, even though the returned recordset is stored as an object property and still returns a Resource ID number when called later.

Can anyone see why the call to the `getNextRow()` method below is unable to return the next row in the recordset?  This worked fine in MySQL.

```
class TestClass
{
//Properties
public $result; //Holds the record set returned from a query
public $sql; //Holds the value of the last sql query sent

    function goQuery($sql)
    {
        $this->sql = $sql;

        if($con = db2_connect("MASTER", "DB2USER", "DB2PASSWORD"))
        {
            echo "<li>Connected to master database</li>";   
        }

        if($this->result = db2_exec($con, $sql))
        {
            echo "<li>SQL Query ran successfully</li>"; 
        }

        //Just proving some data can be returned as this point
        $row = db2_fetch_assoc($this->result);
        if(sizeof($row) > 0)
        {
            echo "<li>db2_fetch_assoc returned a record in the resultset (Resource ID: " . $this->result . ") that has " . sizeof($row) . " fields</li>";   
        }

        //Just proving some data can be returned as this point
        $row = $this->getNextRow();
        if(sizeof($row) > 0)
        {
            echo "<li>getNextRow() returned a record in the resultset (Resource ID: " . $this->result . ") the has " . sizeof($row) . " fields</li>";   
        }
    }

    function getNextRow()
    {
        if($row = db2_fetch_assoc($this->result))
        {
            return $row;    
        }
            else
        {
            echo "<li>No results found in " . $this->result . "</li>";  
        }
    }
}

$q = new TestClass();

echo "<h2>Running query TestClass->goQuery()</h2>";
echo "<ul>";
$q->goQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
echo "</ul>";

echo "<h2>Trying to fetch a result using TestClass->getNextRow()</h2>";
echo "<ul>";
$row = $q->getNextRow();
echo "</ul>";
```

This currently produces this output:

```
Running query TestClass->goQuery()

Connected to master database
SQL Query ran successfully
db2_fetch_assoc returned a record in the resultset (Resource ID: Resource id #12) that has 25 fields
getNextRow() returned a record in the resultset (Resource ID: Resource id #12) the has 25 fields
Trying to fetch a result using TestClass->getNextRow()

No results found in Resource id #12
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve by using a persistent connection:

```
$con = db2_pconnect("MASTER", "USER", "PASSWORD")
```

It looks like the DB2 connection and all returned resources stop existing at the end of the function in which they were called - unless a persistent connection is used.

This is unique to DB2 as I found persistent connections weren't necessary to achieve this in MySQL.